# XSD simpleContent with WCF/Web API

Tags: json, xml, wcf, xsd, asp.net-web-api2

I have an issue generating proper XML/JSON with my WebService, when handling simpleContent tags in the XSD.

First of all, I only have an XSD file (no WSDL), with this content (simplified) :

```
<xs:complexType name="VerticalDataValue">    
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="NCADevicePublication:Double">
      <xs:attribute name="unit" type="NCADevicePublication:VerticalUnitEnum" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="Double">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:double" />
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="VerticalUnitEnum">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="ft"></xs:enumeration>
    <xs:enumeration value="m"></xs:enumeration>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I then generate my class using Xsd.exe.

What I expect for this structure, on the XML output:

```
<altitudeCoordinate unit="ft">2.1</altitudeCoordinate>
```

What I get :

```
<altitudeCoordinate>
  <Value>2.1</Value>
    <unit>ft</unit>
    <unitSpecified>true</unitSpecified>
</altitudeCoordinate>
```

The same for JSON, I expect :

```
"altitudeCoordinate": {
        "@unit": "ft",
        "text": "2.1"
 }
```

But I get :

```
"altitudeCoordinate":{
        "unit": "ft",
        "unitSpecified": "true,
        "Value": 2.1
```

I saw on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb942828(v=vs.85).aspx) that the simpleContent restriction is not recognized by Xsd.Exe.

Is there any way to have this kind of "standard" output or .Net just cannot do it?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I was able to make it work for my WCF Service. The solution was quite simple... just put [XmlSerializerFormat] at the top of the Interface, and voilà.
The reason is that the default serializer (DataContractSerializer) cannot handle xml attributes correctly.
Also, be aware that WCFStorm uses the DataContractSerializer as well : I discovered that even when using the XmlSerializer, I had bad XML in WCFStorm. I then checked with SoapUI, and it was working! (lost a few hours still).

So now, let's make this work on my Web API project, for JSON....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured a solution. Just a reminder : my goal was not to touch at the generated class.

**For SOAP/XML**
As stated in my update, the solution was pretty easy, I just put the following attribute on the WCF interface :

```
[XmlSerializerFormat]
```

**For REST/JSON**
The solution was to define MetadataType classes for the "bothering" classes that were not well converted.

For example, here is how the VerticalDataValue class is defined in the auto-generated file (I stripped the attributes and namespaces):

```
public partial class VerticalDataValue {

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public VerticalUnitEnum unit;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool unitSpecified;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
public double Value;
}
```

I created another file, containing all MetadataType classes, defined like following:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(VerticalDataValueMetaClass))]
public partial class VerticalDataValue { }
public class VerticalDataValueMetaClass
{
    [JsonProperty("@unit")]
    public VerticalUnitEnum unit;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool unitSpecified

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public double value;
}
```

Be aware that this is only possible if your base class is partial.

Of course, this is high-maintenance code, but at least this does not mess with the auto-generated class.